# How to secure connection between different GAEs?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

For some reason I need to create two GAEs with project A and B:

- A(flex env) is a proxy server bounded with Endpoint and restrict access with API key.
- B(standard env) is real server which does real jobs.(B cannot apply Endpoint framework)
- Client only awares proxy server address and send all requests to A

Now I would like to secure connection between A and B. In other words, B is only accessible from A. Is there any way to achieve it? (Firewall not work here because GAE has not static IP range.)

Comment: sorry that I didn't mention that A is flex environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you want to determine the identity of the App Engine app that is
>   making a request to your App Engine app, you can use the request
>   header X-Appengine-Inbound-Appid. This header is added to the request
>   by the URLFetch service and is not user modifiable, so it safely
>   indicates the requesting application's ID, if present.
>
> In your application handler, you can check the incoming ID by reading
>   the X-Appengine-Inbound-Appid header and comparing it to a list of IDs
>   allowed to make requests.
>
> Note: The X-Appengine-Inbound-Appid header is only set if the call is
>   made to the appspot.com domain. If the app has a custom domain, this
>   header will not be set.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/appidentity/#asserting_identity_to_other_app_engine_apps

This should work the same for all App Engine standard environments.

Comment: sorry that I didn't mention that A is flex environment; is this solution still suitable?